# kik bot server receiving POST but bot.onTextMessage(...) is not responding

Tags: node.js, api, chat, chatbot, kik

I am running node.js (v5.10.1) on an ubuntu server (14.04.4 LTS).
And the npm (@kikinteractive/kik) has been installed.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kikinteractive/kik)

Here is the server.js file I have written:

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util');
const http = require('http');
const Bot  = require('@kikinteractive/kik');

const port = 80;

let bot = new Bot({
    username: 'botnamehere',
    apiKey: 'blablabla-1001-0110-1001-2112blablabla'
});

bot.onTextMessage((message)=>{
    message.reply(message.body);
});


var server = http.createServer(bot.incoming());
server.on('request', function (request, response) {
    bot.incoming();
    // I added this to write the request 
    //   so that I could verify my server was receiving from kik
    console.log(request.method);
    console.log(request.headers);
    console.log(request.url);
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("./logfile.log", JSON.stringify(request.headers), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The kik request was saved!");
    }); 

});

server.listen(port);
```

Note: An IP address was used for the kik configuration webhook, and the server is listening on port 80.

I know that my kik configuration seems to be correct as the text messages from the kik app result in POST requests at my server, shown here (key data has been replaced for this posted question):

{ "host": "ipaddressofhost", "x-kik-signature": "8EEBLA44C3BB9769BLAE56E7E9CBLA2BA4179445", "content-type": "application/json", "x-kik-username": "botname", "x-cloud-trace-context": "272c0f7616d6189bla9540d1e47668f5/5407793903926111947", "content-length": "307", "connection": "Keep-alive", "user-agent": "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~bot-dashboard)", "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,br" }

And I know that my server can send messages to kik, as I have tested the following and confirmed the message received in the kik app:

bot.send(Bot.Message.text('What!'), 'username');

So the question is:  If my configuration seems correct, in that I am able to verify a POST at my server, and the kik npm is installed correctly as I am able to send messages from my server to kik, why is bot.incoming() and bot.onTextMessage just sitting there rendering my server a big, dumb, expensive brick?  What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify:  No matter what I have tried in the onTextMessage handler, using all examples provided by Kik docs, and any I have found elsewhere, none of the server.js examples worked as expected on my server;  but when I add console.log(request.headers), I can see that my server does receive a POST from Kik.  What in the what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you set your webhook properly. 
In your snippet, you don't specify the `incomingPath` option, so it will default to `/incoming`, so make sure your webhook is set to `http://1.2.3.5:80/incoming`. All requests to another path will be dropped.

Otherwise, you can specify it by doing

```
let bot = new Bot({
    username: '...',
    apiKey: '...',
    incomingPath: '/yourincomingpath'
});
```

Comment: The incomingPath wasn't exactly the issue, but it did point to the issue.  The documentation seems to indicate that baseUrl is optional, so I left that out, assuming it would simply default to the baseUrl of the running app, which is where I was listening anyway.  I did three things:  I changed my configuration to use port 8080 (which  was probably not necessary but I did it anyway just to match their example); I updated to the latest version of @kikinteractive/kik (v2.0.2); and I set the baseUrl to match the webhook in the kik configuration as "h ttp://ipaddress:8080".  Now it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let server = http
    .createServer(bot.incoming())
    .listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Does this work?

I'm not sure what the exact issue is but if that should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using an IP address for your webhook. If that IP is local, then the Kik APIs will not be able to send messages to your server.

I would suggest using a service like https://ngrok.com/ to expose your server to Kik during development. All you have to do is run `ngrok start 8080` in your terminal and you will get a URL that will redirect everything to the 8080 port on your local machine.

Comment: The ip address is public.  My server does receive the POST from the kik user, but the onTextMessage does not trigger any reply to the kik user.